# Windows E482: Cannot create file

Tags: error

I have been using [this bookmark plugin](https://github.com/MattesGroeger/vim-bookmarks) for a while, on Linux. I want to start using it on Windows as well, so I have added this conditional setting:

```
" vim-bookmarks
  let g:bookmark_sign = '⭕'
  let g:bookmark_save_per_working_dir = 0
  let g:bookmark_manage_per_buffer = 0
  let g:bookmark_display_annotation = 1
  if has('unix')
    let g:bookmark_auto_save_file = $XDG_DATA_HOME .'/vim-bookmarks'
  elseif has('win32')
    let g:bookmark_auto_save_file = $VIMFILES .'/vim-bookmarks'
  endif
```

I get the following error when trying to change buffer:

```
Error detected while processing BufLeave Autocommands for "*"..function SNR>51_auto_save[2]..BookmarkSave:
line    4: 
E482: Cannot create file $HOME/vimfiles/vim-bookmarks
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

The path appears to be correct. I have tried making an empty file at `C:\Users\jason\vimfiles\vim-bookmarks`, but it doesn't help.

Comment: You usually get that error when trying to write a file in a write-protected directory. How did you create that `C:\Users\jason\vimfiles\`? How do you run Vim?

Comment: @romainl In Windows I usually run is from `cmd.exe` shell. I can save a file in that directory with no problems and the permissions are writeable from my user account. The vimfiles directory contains all the vim configuration and it's created by a script which copies over my Linux configuration from WSL. I could have this `vim-bookmarks` file created in `%USERPROFILE%` instead, but I am not sure how.

Comment: Yes, you can use any available environment variable.

Comment: @romainl I changed it to `$USERPROFILE` and it works fine. Strange that it couldn't write to `$VIMFILES`. Cheers.

Comment: On my machine `$VIMFILES` do not exist. What is the result of `:echo "'" . $VIMFILE . "'"` on your machine?

Comment: How did you initialize `$VIMFILES`? The error message mentions `$HOME/vimfiles`, so you probably did something like `let $VIMFILES = '$HOME/vimfiles'` inside of Vim or `set VIMFILES=$HOME/vimfiles` outside of Vim (e.g., in the Windows command prompt). That should either be `let $VIMFILES = $HOME . '/vimfiles'` or `set VIMFILES=%HOME%/vimfiles`. (You can replace `HOME` with `USERPROFILE` if `$HOME` (resp. `%HOME%`) ist not defined

Comment: @JürgenKrämer Yes, that's it. I had set it using `let $VIMFILES = "$HOME/vimfiles"` and `let $VIMFILES = "$HOME/.config/vim"` for Linux, so I could use the same paths elsewhere in the configuration, but I have fixed them now. Thanks. You could make that an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message mentions `$HOME/vimfiles`, so you probably initialized `$VIMFILES` by doing something like `let $VIMFILES = '$HOME/vimfiles'` inside of Vim or `set VIMFILES=$HOME/vimfiles` outside of Vim (e.g., in the Windows command prompt).

That should either be `let $VIMFILES = $HOME . '/vimfiles'` or `set VIMFILES=%HOME%/vimfiles`. (You can replace `HOME` with `USERPROFILE` if `$HOME` (resp. `%HOME%` in Windows parlance) is not defined.) Otherwise not the expanded value of `$HOME` is used but the name of the variable itself (including the leading dollar sign).

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
let g:bookmark_auto_save_file = expand('~/vimfiles/vim-bookmarks')
```